# Python Accessing Lists or Dicts from Names in String Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python function that picks the name of an existing list at random from a text file of existing list names, and returns the chosen lists name as a string. Outside the function, the script should then print the contents of that list.

What I'm having trouble with is figuring out **how to (outside the function) print/access the list whose name is returned as a string by the function.**

If I create the lists outside the function:

```
list_number_one = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']
list_number_two = ['bananas', 'grapes', 'unbridled existentialism']
```

and the function itself looks like:

```
def pick_a_list(list1, list2):
    list_of_lists = [list1, list2]
    random_list = random.choice(list_of_lists)
    return random_list
```

when I use the function...

```
chosen_list = pick_a_list('list_number_one', 'list_number_two')
```

if it returns the string 'list_number_one' as the randomly chosen list, how do I then (outside the function):

```
print (chosen_list)
```

and get in return:

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']
```

In the actual script, assume my only option is taking string variables as the input for the list names, inconvenient as it may be. And the number of lists I'm working with is very large. I searched high and low for the answer but all of the Q&A's I'm finding are about assigning key/value pairs based on variable input. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I don't want to just bomb the function with global variables.

Comment: Why are you passing strings when you want to choose *lists*? Pass the lists.. "In the actual script, assume my only option is taking string variables as the input for the list names, inconvenient as it may be" Why should we assume that? What possible reason could that be?

Comment: You should use a single dict to contain the lists.

Comment: You can, of course, use the string to extract the list form the `globals()` namespace dict, but why would you want to abuse the global namespace that way? Rather, you should organize your program such that you put the data you need in an appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your lists are forced at the hands of users like such (because why else would you torture yourself to depend on string values for your variables?):

```
list_name = input("enter list name: ")
list_value = input("enter list values separated by commas: ")
```

An easy way to counter that is to use dictionary to store your lists:

```
my_lists = {}
while has_input: 
    list_name = input("enter list name: ")
    list_values = input("enter list values separated by commas: ")
    my_lists{list_name} = list_values.split(',')
    # TODO: code exit loop condition for has_input = False

# my_lists:
# {'list_number_one': ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'],
#  'list_number_two': ['bananas', 'grapes', 'unbridled existentialism']}

chosen_list = pick_a_list(my_lists['list_number_one'], my_lists['list_number_two'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were sending in strings, not the lists themselves. If you remove the quotes from around the list objects passed to the function as follows:

```
chosen_list = pick_a_list(list_number_one, list_number_two)
```

You get `['bananas', 'grapes', 'unbridled existentialism']` if your random selection matches what my system chose.

Comment: Understood, but again, I'm reading from a text file of list names as my input. Even without the randomizing part, the question remains, if I have a string that is the name of a list, how do I call or access the list whose name I've just read from the text file?